# Angular 5 not working in IE 11

Tags: angular, visual-studio-2017, internet-explorer-11

My application is using, 
1. Angular CLI
2 Visual studio 2017
3. Angular 5

When I try to run it in IE 11, it does not work. None of the solutions on internet worked.
I couldn't find the polyfills.js file as mentioned on Angular documentation.
I tried to add the script sections mentioned on Angular documentation.

Nothing worked.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: "Not working" is not a very good diagnostic. Do you get any errors? Do you have *any* information about why it isn't working as expected?

Comment: the polyfills.ts files is usually in the src folder in the root of your project

src/polyfills.ts

Comment: Hi Tadman, I see below syntax error in the Console,
"Error: (SystemJS) Syntax error. Evaluating http://localhost/app/app.module.js".
Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

There is a file called polyfills.ts, inside that file there are alot of imports commented out. Uncomment those, and you should be okay after that.

such as:

```
    /***************************************************************************************************
 * BROWSER POLYFILLS
 */

/** IE9, IE10 and IE11 requires all of the following polyfills. **/
// import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
// import 'core-js/es6/object';
// import 'core-js/es6/function';
// import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
// import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
// import 'core-js/es6/number';
// import 'core-js/es6/math';
// import 'core-js/es6/string';
// import 'core-js/es6/date';
// import 'core-js/es6/array';
// import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
// import 'core-js/es6/map';
// import 'core-js/es6/weak-map';
// import 'core-js/es6/set';
/** IE10 and IE11 requires the following for NgClass support on SVG elements */
// import 'classlist.js';  // Run `npm install --save classlist.js`.
/** IE10 and IE11 requires the following for the Reflect API. */
// import 'core-js/es6/reflect';
```

Comment: I couldn't find polyfills.js. I created this application using Angular CLI and copied files manually to my Visual Studio project folder. So do you suggest to create this file in root folder?

Comment: If the project was created via CLI then the polyfills.ts file should be there, I think maybe forgot to copy to visual studio code.

But you can generate new angular project and copy polyfills.ts

it should look similar to this: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/tests/@angular_devkit/build_angular/hello-world-app/src/polyfills.ts

Comment: Taranjit: I tried creating a new project using Visual Studio 2017 - Angular template. And this does not create polyfills.ts file. Will try with Angualr CLI...

Comment: you could just use the polyfills.ts from the git repo I posted, or just create a new project and copy the polyfills.ts over and then try.

Comment: Taranjit: I added polyfills.ts and still keep getting the below error message. However, It works with new test project using Angular CLI----------
{description: "Syntax erro...", message: "Syntax erro...", name: "Error", originalErr: Error {...}, stack: "SyntaxError...", Symbol()_m.jjnz40riedm: undefined, Symbol()_n.jjnz40riedm: undefined, Symbol()_o.jjnz40riedm: undefined, Symbol()_p.jjnz40riedm: undefined, Symbol()_q.jjnz40riedm: undefined, Symbol()_r.jjnz40riedm: undefined, Symbol()_s.jjnz40riedm: undefined, Symbol()_t.jjnz40riedm: undefined, Symbol(rxSubscriber)_u.jjnz40riedm: undefined}

Comment: Also get error: ---- Error: Syntax error -- Evaluating http://localhost:7072/app/app.module.js -- Evaluating http://localhost:7072/app/main.js -- Loading app

Comment: Yes copied the same exact polyfills file in my project root folder and included in my VS 2017 project.

Comment: Interesting thing: I removed polyfills file and just changed es6 to es5 in my tsconfig file and everything works in IE 11. However it is very very slow. But it works. Thank you.

Comment: nice, grats! Just look at network tab and see what's causing performance issues or build for production ng build --prod and see if any difference, ng serve --prod